# How to remove stray ^M and <96> from text file before import into sas

Tags: unix, carriage-return, dos2unix

I receive a pipe-delimited text file from a user that populates an excel spreadsheet using screen scrapes, so the data is a mess.  It is full of random `^M (carriage returns)` and `<96> (windows en dash)` throughout which causes the import to be incomplete.

I have tried the `dos2unix`, and I receive an error that there was a problem with the conversion.  I removed all the `^M` by using this solution I found on this site:

```
tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile
```

The `<96>` characters remain.  What would be the comparable `'/r'` for these dashes?  Or perhaps there is a better solution?  I would actually like to replace the "bad" dashes with "good" dashes if possible.

Comment: Could you share a sample of the text file and a desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just clean up the file using SAS instead?  If your lines as shorter than 32,767 characters then it would be simple.

```
data _null_;
  infile 'input-file' termstr=LF ;
  file 'output-file' termstr=LF ;
  input;
  _infile_=translate(compress(_infile_,'0D'x),'-','96'x);
  put _infile_;
run;
```

If the lines are longer you can read the data field by field and fix it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the octal value using the command `cat file.txt | od` and remove it using `tr` just like you did with ^M characters.